# How to run a button on protected sheets in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a protected file that other users can edit some specific cell but when they going to click the Submit button, there is this error saying "You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit." Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are protecting the whole sheet and excepting some ranges.

Do it the opposite.

Only protect the ranges you do not want users to edit and leave the sheet unprotected.

Then the drawings could be clicked.